# change language of the site on select menu change is not working- MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: php, laravel

I installed this package "https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization".

I want to translate the site based on a select menu, so when the user selects a language in the select menu the site content should translate to the selected language using the above package.

But its not working, with code below when the user change the language in the form it appears "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\ MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php.

Then I have this class:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Translate
{
    protected $default = 'en';

    protected $languages = [
         'en',
         'nl',
         'fr',
    ];

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if($request->has('language')) {
            $lang = $request->language;
            if(array_search($lang, $this->languages) === false) {
                $lang = $this->default;
            }

            $request->session()->put('lang', $lang);
        }

        \LaravelLocalization::setLocale( $request->session()->get('lang') );

        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

And in the in kernel.php:

```
  protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,  // <-- without this one, it wont work
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\Translate::class,   // <-- Add it here
        ],
        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
    ];
```

And the select menu for the user change language:

```
form method="get" id="translate">
  <select name="language" class="form-control font-weight-normal text-gray" id="language" onchange="localize">
    <option value="en">English</option>
    <option value="fr">French</option>
    <option value="es">Spanish</option>
    <option>5</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 var myFormName = "translate";
 $('#language').on('change', function)(){

     $('#translate).submit();
  });
});
```

Comment: That error is usually connected to the wrong http method being used. Check your routes that you are submitting to it should probably be changed from Route::get to post

Comment: Thanks, but same error with post.